# Limit points of $A=\{1+\frac{m}{n}, m,n \in \mathbb{N}\}$

Tags: analysis

What is the set of limit points of $A=\{1+\frac{m}{n}, m,n \in \mathbb{N}\}$.

My try:

I know $a_{mn} = 1+\frac{m}{n}$ is not convergent. Could I conclude that the set $A^{'}$ is empty ?!

Comment: $A = (1, \infty) \cap \mathbb{Q}$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your set contains **all** possible choices of natural $m,n$. This means that you can construct any positive rational number with them. So your set contains all rational numbers greater than or equal to one, which is dense in $[1,\infty)$, and so the limit points are $[1,\infty)$.

Comment: The set does not contain $1$, although it has it as a limit point.

Comment: @Kaind depends on whether you think of $0$ as a natural number. I do (although then you cannot take $n=0$).